# How to purchase all songs at a time from iTunes which are returned from iTunes search API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes, itunes-store, shazam

i am working on an music app by using which we can listen,buy(iTunes),share the songs.My problem is when user search for a song with a key word we can search for that on iTunes using iTunes API,we have to provide an option that purchase all songs or selected songs among which are returned by search API in a single transaction,just like in shazam music app.[image]
is it possible to purchase multiple songs(or albums) at a time,please guide me to do this.

thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got an solution for this.i'm posting answer because this may help to others.

We can do this by using [AffiliateColections](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/collection.html) feature in iTunes.Actually this whole process is to be done by our app server side.if we send selected songs data to our server,then our server will request iTunes to create a Collection with those items.For more have a look at
[iTunes Affiliate Program](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes_app_store_affiliate_program.html)